# Laravel 5 - Determine if route belongs to user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

What I am looking to achieve here is to have the username set as `myapp.com/username`. I can achieve this by doing:

```
/*
 *  Other route logic, containing static-url pages, such as 
 *  myapp.com/login so that it overrides any usernames
 */

Route::get('/{username}', function($username) {
    return $username . "'s profile.";
});
```

However, I also want to include company pages following the same rule. For example, `myapp.com/janes-bakery`. But I cannot seem to achieve this because Laravel automatically stops searching for routes if it comes across one that returns nothing. Instead it will just throw a 404 page.

I did think that I could use something similar along these lines:

```
Route::get('/{slug}', ['as' => 'profile', function($slug) {

    $company = \App\Models\Company::where('slug', '=', $slug)->get();

    if($company->count() > 0) {
        return "Company found.";
    }

    $user = \App\User::where('username', '=', $slug)->get();

    if($user->count() > 0) {
       return "User found.";
    }

    abort(404);

}]);
```

Which works fine, however I feel as though it's bad practice. Besides that, I cannot access suffix routes based on the company/user. For example `myapp.com/jane/friends` or `myapp.com/janes-bakery/services`.

Does anybody have any recommendations on how to go about this? I am finding it very hard to think of any solutions. Thank you in advance!

P.S. It is important the URLs have no correlation, e.g. no `myapp.com/company/user` (or vice versa), `myapp.com/company_name_here` and `myapp.com/users_name_here` are two totally separate things.

Answer (score 0):

You can stick with your route and make another route with `company/user` pattern. You can do it this way.

Create another route with company and user parameter.

```
Route::get('{company}/{user}', function($company, $user){
  dd($company, $user);
});
```

And you need to put this route above your profile route because, in laravel, the first route present will be processed before the others routes below.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however this is not the kind of answer I was looking for. I do not wish to link the company to the user. What I want however is to separate slugs